# C# Programming arrays

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that takes the scores of homework assignments, puts them in a array, then averages them. But I need to make it so that these grades range from 1-10. I am not sure how to make it only accept Numbers 1-10. Everything else is complete.

Here is what i have so far:

```
namespace AverageScore
{
class AverageScore
{
    //prompt user to enter the size of the array 
    public int GetNum()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many scores you want to save!");
        string strNum = Console.ReadLine();
        int num = int.Parse(strNum);
        return num;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AverageScore scoreObject = new AverageScore();
        int arraySize = scoreObject.GetNum();

        //define a double array to save scores
        double[] scoreArray = new double[arraySize];

        string inValue = "";
        double sum = 0,
            intValue;


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter all homework scores");
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < arraySize)
        {

            inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            while (double.TryParse(inValue, out intValue) == false)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Invalid input = 0 stored in intValue");
              inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            sum += intValue;
            scoreArray[counter] = intValue;
            counter++;

        }

        Array.Sort(scoreArray);
        double lowest= scoreArray[0];
        double highest = scoreArray[arraySize-1];
        sum = sum - lowest - highest;
        double average = sum / arraySize;
        Console.WriteLine("The average grade of the scores is" + average);
        Console.WriteLine("The Lowest Score is" + lowest);
        Console.WriteLine("The Highest Score is" + highest);
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: where is the connection to functional-programming?

Comment: You've already solved the invalid input problem, although the `".... = 0 "` part is a little misleading. Now solve the `intvar < 1 || intVar > 10` problem the same way.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is to restrict a input to 1-10 correct?

Why not just:

```
public int InputGrade()
{
    Console.Clear();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a grade [1-10]");
    var grade = -1;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade))
        return InputGrade();

    if (grade < 1 || grade > 10)
        return InputGrade();
    
    return grade;
}
```

Then you should be able to use it like this and it is cleaner:

```
while (counter < arraySize)
{
    var grade = InputGrade();
    sum += grade;
    scoreArray[counter++] = grade;
}
```

**Recommendation**

Indeed you should refactor the input from the calculation part - you code will get much more cleaner and more readable:

```
IEnumerable<int> InputGrades()
{
    var count = GetNum();
    var grades = new List<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
       grades.Add(InputGrade());

    return grades;
}

void OutputScores(IEnumerable<int> grades)
{
    var scores  = grades.Cast<doulbe>().ToArray();
    var lowest  = scores.Min();
    var highest = scores.Max();
    var average = scores.Average();

    Console.WriteLine("The average grade of the scores is" + average);
    Console.WriteLine("The Lowest Score is" + lowest);
    Console.WriteLine("The Highest Score is" + highest);
}
```

Comment: I need the program to be able to only input numbers 1-10, but be able to put as many number as possible.

Comment: sure just use this function for every grade you need ... I just refactored the code out so things look cleaner - you can of course use this inside a loop or whatever you wish

Comment: @HenkHolterman if you cheat, do it right - anyway it's not on me to decide what might be *obvious* help - it's on me to give reasonable advice, and recursion is the most obvious and simple solution in this case - btw: the OP added the *functional-programming*  tag in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the while loop condition to check that the number is in range (added a simple string format to present the previous invalid entry):

```
while (double.TryParse(inValue, out intValue) == false || intValue < 1.0 || intValue > 10.0**)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Invalid input = {0} stored in intValue", intValue));
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
while (counter < arraySize){
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
    while (true){
        if(double.TryParse(inValue ,out intValue) {
            if(intValue >=1 && intValue <=10){
                break;
            }else{                      
                Console.WriteLine("Input must be in the range 1-10");
                inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input = 0 stored in intValue");
            inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    sum += intValue;
    scoreArray[counter] = intValue;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: When I run this I get "Input must be in the range 1-10" running infinatly

Comment: below `Console.WriteLine("Input must be in the range 1-10");` you must add :  `inValue = Console.ReadLine(); `

Answer (score 0):

Uses a loop to check if the value entered is correct:

```
while (int.Parse(inValue) < 1 || int.Parse(inValue) > 10)  inValue = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?